# How to merge images in React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, image-manipulation

I would like to merge multiple images into one by stacking them one above another in the new image. U have the uri of the images and i would like to get the uri of the resulting image. I saw that there are multiple packages for that but they require `react-native link` and I'm currenty using Expo. Is there a way to get what I want without ejecting and swithing to the bare workflow?
[image]

Comment: i dont use expo , but packages didnt work as expected :( so you need to create your own